# copy arrays to multiple cells in matlab wihtout for loop (possibly with deal function)

Tags: matlab, vectorization

I would like to copy an array into consecutive cell locations.  For example:

```
A = cell(2,4);

for m = 1:2

  if condition == true
    A{m,1:2} = [1 1 1];
    A{m,3:end} = [4];
  else
    A{m,:} = [2 2];
  end
end
```

I would like the end state for condition = true for m = 1 and false for m = 2 to look like this:

```
A = {{[1 1 1], [1 1 1], [4], [4]},...
     {[2 2], [2 2], [2 2], [2 2]}}
```

I hope my syntax is right for end result...
It looks like deal might help but can't quite figure it out with double index on A.
Again, not looking for a for loop solution.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your expected output creates nested cell arrays, but your code suggests you are trying to create a cell matrix. This would be `A = {[1 1 1], [1 1 1], [4], [4];
     [2 2], [2 2], [2 2], [2 2]}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fill an cell array with repeating elements, using:

```
A(1,1:2)=repmat({[1,1,1]},1,2)
A(1,3:end)=repmat({[4]},1,2)
A(2,:)=repmat({[2,2]},1,4)
```

Comment: Thank you.  It was the switch from braces to parenthesis on left hand side of equation that I was missing.